# Creating Java libraries compatible with Android SDK

Tags: android

I want to create a Java library like SLF4J which can run since certain Android version (e.g. Froyo/2.2).

The thing is, I can't be sure if some methods I use are already available on that Android version. For example, `"String".isEmpty()` is not available in Froyo. How should I know this, unless I create the library project as Android Library project?

Making the project as an Android library project is not easy to test. Robolectric is also tricky with Gradle.

I'm expecting something like simple Java Maven project which uses subset of Java API available in certain Android version. Is it possible? Like, I create a new SLF4J library without involving non-existent methods in Android.

Thanks

Comment: This should be tagged with the specific build tool you're having problems with.  You mention Gradle and Maven, but it's not clear if you're using either of those.

Comment: Doesn't matter the build tools. I can use both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that there are differences between the Android SDK and other Java APIs, so if you build and test your code as anything other than an Android library, you may miss problems.  For example, just the other day I found a bug in API 19 (Android 4.4) where `DecimalFormat` produces `BigDecimal`s differently than it does in J2SE SDKs.

But if you must do this, the easiest way is probably to create it as an Android library project and build it against the Froyo SDK to ensure all the methods are available.  Then take the same code and create different build files to build it for your preferred test framework.

Comment: I agree with you. I really hate this actually. I'm supposed to create a core library with can be shared with other Java applications. Android should provide a way out to this problem. At least creating SDK profiles just like in Java 8. And also be sure the behavior is the same (not like your `DecimalFormat` problem)